# Call stack and Breakpoints windows are empty when debugging c# in VS2022 v.17.3.3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I am debugging simple test c# project. My breakpoints are being hit, however breakpoint window and call stack window are empty. Any advise why it is and how to enable it will be greatly appreciated. Thanks[image]

Comment: For future reference, please don't post a huge screenshot that is 90% empty. Resize your window so that it shows what you need to show and the minimum that you don't. ALWAYS make the effort to do ALL you can to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I apologize, will edit my question shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting the machine solved the issue. Now breakpoints and call stack show data.

Comment: I noticed mine was the same today and had come to offer moral support. I guess I'll try a reboot too. It was probably something to do with the most recent VS update.

Comment: yes, restarting visual studio solved the issue for me